# LiveData observes twice instead of only one

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata

I'm using MVVM as architecture on my app, but I watch an unexpected escenario in the observer code: Inside the observer always entered one time before get the real value.

```
myViewModel.getUserInfo().observe(this, androidx.lifecycle.Observer { user ->
        if (user!= null) {

        } else {
            //THE FIRST TIME THROW HERE
        }
```

In my viewModel I have this:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    fun getUserInfo(): MutableLiveData<UserInfoResponse> {

        val liveData: MutableLiveData<UserInfoResponse> = MutableLiveData()
        liveData.postValue(UserInfoResponse("user"))
       
        return liveData
    }
```

Can anyone got the idea that is happening?
Thanks

Comment: Can you try? `observe(viewLifeCycleOwner) {  user -> }` ?

Comment: I had the same result.

Comment: This is how asynchronicity works, and it is expected behavior

Answer (score 0):

[`postValue()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData#postValue(T))

> Posts a task to a main thread to set the given value. So if you have a following code executed in the main thread:

```
 liveData.postValue("a");
 liveData.setValue("b");
```

> The value "b" would be set at first and **later the main thread would override it with the value "a"**.
> If you called this method multiple times before a main thread executed a posted task, only the last value would be dispatched.

At a guess, you're posting that value *before* you return the `LiveData`, but it actually gets **set** *after* the observer has been added and received the first value. When that happens, the observer is called again with the second, posted value.

You've mentioned adding and removing fragments, and I'm assuming they're using the same `ViewModel`, so when they start observing the `LiveData` it already has a value set from earlier, and the observer receives that immediately. The `post`ed value comes later.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it clarified me a lot. Anyway the method in ViewModel is called twice. Is it possible that when ViewModel was created (injection), the method have been called?

Comment: You mean ``getUserInfo()`` is called twice? The only place you've shown it being called is when you're setting up that observer - you'd have to see where else it gets called from (put the cursor on it and press Alt+F7/``Find Usages`` in the menu) and check it's not happening more than it's supposed to

Comment: Yes, that is my problem. I call it only one time, For that reason I think the issue comes when I replace the Fragment instead of add it. So every time I replace it, the method in ViewModel is called.